# Selenium Webdriver: Scrollbars are getting in way of click action

Tags: javascript, c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I'm testing on a simulated mobile screen so screen space is at a premium. I'm using the following code to bring the element into view before clicking it, however, on chrome the scrollbar overlays don't clear before the click action occurs.

```
IJavaScriptExecutor je = (IJavaScriptExecutor)Driver.Instance;

je.ExecuteScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true); window.scrollBy(50, -200);", element);

Thread.Sleep(700);
```

I could make the sleep longer, but that would slow down my tests dramatically.  I've tried everything I can think of and nothing seems to work.

Things I've tried

Disabling the scrollbar overlays when initializing chromedriver. (Didn't remove scroll overlays)
`chromeOptions.AddArguments("disable-overlay-scrollbar")`

Using Actions api

```
 Actions btnAction = new Actions(Driver.Instance);
 btnAction.MoveToElement(element).Click().Perform();
```

`MoveToElement` also has an argument for offsetting, but as far as I can tell, that doesn't effect how the element is positioned in the window.

Has any one else ever run into this issue? If so, how'd you resolve it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could use explicit wait instead of `Thread.Sleep(700)` to make sure the element is clickable before clicking on it

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(element)).Click();
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I've tried that as well.  I don't think selenium recognizes the scroll bars as being in the way.  I still get the same error when trying to wait for clickable.